# 'System.NullReferenceException' while defining an object XNA C#

Tags: c#-4.0, nullreferenceexception, xna-4.0

I've recently been trying to make a game, and decided to start from scratch. However, I quickly encountered an error that wasn't a problem in the previous session of my game.
Me and my friend ran through several ideas of what might cause the error however we haven't been able to find.

Apparently it somehow creates an error when I'm trying to load an object using a different class(UI.UILoader) The main class is as followed:

```
namespace WindowsGame1.Classes
{    
    public static Game1 instance;
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    public MouseState mouseState;
    public KeyboardState keyState;
    public SpriteFont debugFont;
    Instance inst;
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        debugFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("debugFont");
        inst.Load();
        UI.UILoader.Load();
        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }
```

The Class UILoader can be seen beneath where it tries to load two textures using Texture2D. However when it tries to load the first texture I recieve a 'System.NullReferenceException' error.

```
namespace WindowsGame1.Classes.UI
{
    public static class UILoader
    {
        public static Texture2D cursorTexture;
        public static Texture2D buttonTexture;

        public static void Load()
        {
            cursorTexture = Game1.instance.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Interface/Cursor");
            buttonTexture = Game1.instance.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Interface/Cursor");
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it might have something to do me using a different class to load(which I found odd) so I tried moving it all to the load content class in the main class, however, it didn't remove the error but instead of triggering during the loading session it now triggered when I tried to put the object to use(after the object should have been given a value and thus not be null)

I don't believe that the problem is with the picture I try to use since I already added it to the folder I'm using (I would post a picture but i don't have enough reputation)

If anyone have any idea what might be the cause of this error I would be happy to here your thoughts.